# Use pandas asfreq/resample to get the end of the period

Tags: pandas

I am trying to find the mean for each day and put that value as an input for every hour in a year. The problem is that the last day only contains the first hour.

```
rng = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
days = ts.resample('D')
day_mean_in_hours = asfreq('H', method='ffill')
day_mean_in_hours.tail(5)
2011-12-30 20:00:00   -0.606819
2011-12-30 21:00:00   -0.606819
2011-12-30 22:00:00   -0.606819
2011-12-30 23:00:00   -0.606819
2011-12-31 00:00:00   -2.086733
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Is there a nice way to change the frequency to hour and still get the full last day?

Answer (score 0):

You could [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the frame using an hourly DatetimeIndex that covers the last full day.

```
hourly_rng = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', freq='1H', closed='left')
day_mean_in_hours = day_mean_in_hours.reindex(hourly_rng, method='ffill')
```

See [Resample a time series with the index of another time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968313/resample-a-time-series-with-the-index-of-another-time-series) for another example.